# *_join with empty suffix

Tags: r, dplyr

***Fair warning*: this can hang your operating system.**

`*_join()` from `dplyr` fails when either of the left or right suffixes are specified as empty (`''`), e.g.

```
inner_join(data.frame(x=1, y=2),
           data.frame(x=1, y=3),
           by='x',
           suffix=c('', '.b'))
```

Whereas the following works fine:

```
inner_join(data.frame(x=1, y=2),
           data.frame(x=1, y=3),
           by='x',
           suffix=c('.a', '.b'))
```

Meanwhile, the S3 generic `merge()` (base) has no problem with empty suffixes:

```
merge(data.frame(x=1, y=2),
      data.frame(x=1, y=3),
      by='x',
      suffixes=c('', '.b'))
```

dplyr package info:

```
> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.5.0’
```

R version info:

```
> version

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.0                         
year           2016                        
month          05                          
day            03                          
svn rev        70573                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
nickname       Supposedly Educational
```

Comment: Ouch.... that's a nasty one. It actually hangs my R process when trying your one row example. I'd report a bug if I was you.

Comment: Oops I thought I put a fair warning in there, edited. bug report is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: This currently being tracked here https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2228

Answer (score 7):

This was fun when I stumbled across this bug.  The following will accomplish the desired effect using `dplyr` of using suffixes `''` and `.b`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(data.frame(x=1, y=2),
           data.frame(x=1, y=3),
           by='x',
           suffix=c('.a', '.b')) %>%
  setNames(gsub('\\.a$', '', names(.)))
```